# Expression de la conséquence

Tags: grammaire, conjonctions

Dans quelles phrases est-ce qu'on utilise "si bien que" et "à tel point que"?

Quelle est la différence entre "donc" et "alors"?

Quelle est la différence entre "c'est pourquoi" et "c'est pour ça que"?

Answer (score 4):

Toutes ces expressions sont proches, on est dans la nuance.

> Dans quelles phrases est-ce qu'on utilise "si bien que" et "à tel point que"? Quelle est la meilleur traduction en anglais ?

Dans toutes les phrases où on a une accumulation, il y a une notion de *degré* dans "si bien que". L'expression est plus forte que *donc*, qui est plus factuel. on peut l'utiliser pour montrer un agacement.

exemples :

> Il m'a pris mes affaires à tel point que j'ai dû en acheter d'autres.

Dans l'ordre, on a : *A tel point que* > *si bien que* > *donc* > *alors*

> donc / alors

*Donc* montre le lien logique, alors que *alors* montre le lien "temporel" (suite des événements). Noter que "alors que" que j'emploie ici ne fait que montrer une opposition :-)

> pourquoi / pour que

*Pourquoi* s'intéresse à la cause.
*Pour quoi* s'intéresse à la conséquence.

exemples :

> Pourquoi êtes vous venu ? Je m'ennuyais. [Je m'ennuyais, c'est pourquoi je suis venu]
>
> Pour quoi êtes-vous venu ? Pour jouer [Je suis venu pour jouer.]